# entity framework 4.1 two tables with the same property name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, wcf-data-services

i'm having some problems with entity framework and a sql database.
so my problem is this:
in my database there are two tables that have the same property, they are identical in type and length but they are not related in any way. no foreign key whatsoever.
as soon as i start to interact with the database entity framework spits out the famous error:

> error 0019: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name was already defined.

i'm using the code first approach by the way.

this is one of the class representations of the tables:

```
[Table("bo")]
public class TbPBO
{
   [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "O campo de nome nao pode ser nulo")]
    [MaxLength(55, ErrorMessage = "O campo de nome nao pode ter mais que 55 caracteres")]
    [Column("nome", TypeName = "char", Order = 4)]
    public string TbBonome { get; set; }
 }
```

this is the other class representation of the table:

```
[Table("bi")]
public class TbPBi
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "O campo nome nao pode ser nulo")]
    [MaxLength(55, ErrorMessage = "O campo nome nao pode ter mais que 55 caracteres")]
    [Column("nome", TypeName = "char", Order = 62)]
    public string TbBinome { get; set; }
}
```

i've tried modifying my context by using this but without any luck.

```
public class PHCDbContext:DbContext
{
     public PHCDbContext(string connection):base(connection)
     {

        Database.SetInitializer<PHCDbContext>(null);
     }
     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TbPBO>()
            .Map(mbo => { mbo.Properties(tnome => new { tnome.TbBonome }); mbo.ToTable("bo"); });

        modelBuilder.Entity<TbPBi>()
            .Map(mbo => { mbo.Properties(tnome => new { tnome.TbBinome }); mbo.ToTable("bi"); });

    }
}
```

any idea on how to work around this? one more thing. the database must not be changed in any way. i cannot modify it.

help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: Does the class `TbPBO` (or `TbPBi`) have a property called `nome`? It would conflict with the other properties mapped to column name `nome`. Also: What database system are you using? SQL Server or MySql or ...?

Comment: sorry about that. i'm using sql server 2008. and both of the classes have a property called nome. as is on the corresponding tables bi and bo on the database. both of them have a field named nome. and the data that is in the field nome in the table bo is the same in the table bi.

Comment: But why do you map then the property `TbBonome` to the column `nome` when your class already has a property `nome`?

Comment: by that you're saying on the onModelCreating? if so, it was a test to see if would create a workaround. but it didn't. despite using that piece of code in the function or no code whatsoever it doesn't work. i'm still getting the error.

Comment: Is there any inheritance used in your classes?

Comment: ladislav no inheritance, both classes are distinct, each represent a table in the database.

Comment: can this be done? is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

after much googling and trial and error. i discovered ef power tools, installed it and let it reverse engineer my database. i let the process run. it mapped the tables. created the classes and the context. and for what i've been testing the problem is solved.
thanks for the help